# Unexpected C struct pointer size behaviour

Tags: c, pointers, 64-bit

I have some odd behaviour going on in my code which seems to be resulting from the use of a generic pointer though really I am totally uncertain. I have a fairly standard struct which looks like the following:

```
typedef struct {
  char* name;
  PyAutoCFunc ac_func;
  void (*func)();
  PyAutoType type_id;
  int num_args;
  PyAutoType arg_types[MAX_ARG_NUM];
} func_entry;

static func_entry* func_entries;
```

I am storing a static pointer to an array of these struct elements which is allocated on the heap. At the point where I create a new element of this array and insert it, its values look like this...

```
func_entry new_fe;
new_fe.name = malloc(strlen(name) + 1);
strcpy(new_fe.name, name);
... // Init rest of struct

func_entries[num_func_entries] = new_fe;
num_func_entries++;

func_entry* fe = &func_entries[num_func_entries-1];

printf("Setting function '%s' at address '%p', name address '%p'\n", name, fe, fe->name);
```

This outputs.

```
>>> Setting function 'graphics_viewport_set_title' at address '0xfe2d40', name address '0xe40fe0'
```

Notice the size and value of fe->name. I then store this pointer into a hashtable to retrieve later. In the hashtable this is stored as a simple void*. Later when I retrieve the pointer from the hashtable an odd thing happens.

```
func_entry* fe = PyAutoHashtable_Get(func_table, c_func_name);

printf("Getting function '%s' at address '%p', name address '%p'\n", c_func_name, fe, fe->name);
```

Which outputs.

```
>>> Getting function 'graphics_viewport_set_title' at address '0xfe2d40', name address '0x6e6f74656c656b73'
```

The address of fe has clearly been in and out of the hashtable without issue, but the size and address of fe->name  has changed. Even more weirdly is that fe->name is a different size to what it was before and even a different size to fe. Trying to access fe->name gives me a segfault and I am unsure how to proceed.

Out of interest this seems to occur when I use the code in an application with several linked libraries, I'm fairly sure all the code I'm running is 64 bit.

I have run the above code successfully in a separate application and get a correct pointer for fe->name (a smaller one).

I am also running on Ubuntu Linux 64 bit and compiling with gcc.

This is really where my C ignorance shines though as I imagine it could be a million things. Can anyone shine some light?

Comment: You might need to show the code that assigns fe->name.  As shown now, it appears to be uninitialized.

Comment: The address does appear to have changed - 0xfe2d40 != 0x20049e0. I agree with Mark Wilkins - we need to see more code (particularly PyAutoHastable_Get, but the code that sets the name is suspect too).

Comment: Added in fe->name assignment. Don't really want to post the whole of my hashtable implementation as it really is a bulk of code (Though I've been using it for a long time without issues). The fact that it returns the same value for fe makes it less suspect for me.

Comment: Where and how the memory for `func_entries` array is allocated?

Comment: As @Harper said, 0xfe2d40 != 0x20049e0.  You're not getting the same struct pointer back so it's unsurprising that ->name isn't the same.  Most likely 0xfe2d40 is off the end of the func_entries array.

Comment: @KyleJones Opps! That is actually an error in how I copy pasted the question. My Bad!

Comment: @AndreyT The array is allocated on the heap and the pointer to the array is allocated statically in the source file.

Comment: If it works correctly in your unit test code, but not in the application, the problem probably is not with the code you have shown us.  I'm guessing that func_entries and its contents is getting corrupted at some point.

Comment: 0x6e6f74656c656b73 looks like part of a string.  If you take the hex values 6e 6f 74 etc. and interpret them as ASCII characters you get "noteleks".  Reverse the order and you get "skeleton".  So corruption of the func_entries array seems probable.

Comment: Wow - excellent catch. I noticed the ASCII but didn't think to reverse. Skeleton is certainly a word which appears in my codebase often. This is starting to some like a really nasty corruption elsewhere...

Comment: @Daniel Holden: So, do you have enough memory allocated for `func_entries` array? If you overrun `func_entries` array and overlap some other object (or simply some free memory), later changes in that other object will appear as "unexplainable" changes in those offending entries of `func_entries` array. Which is why I want to see how `func_entries` is allocated. More precisely, I want to see how long is `func_entries` when it is allocated.

Answer (score 1):

That address for name looks like the result of memory corruption.  It's completely unaligned, which is unlikely for an address returned by strdup off the heap.

It looks like you're out of scope for the structure you created.  You mentioned it's created on the heap, but in the code it looks like it's probably created on the stack.  This isn't all being done in the same function, is it?  Is the code in the first block in a function that's existed before running the code in the later block?  As soon as you exit that function the memory for that structure ceased to be, even though you retained a pointer to it.  Later, when you pulled the pointer out of the hash table the memory had been overwritten and didn't have the pointer to name there anymore.  If you're going to pass around pointers to structures allocate them dynamically by using malloc.  They're exist until you explicitly get rid of them using free, instead of when the function ends.

Comment: Thanks! I've got a feeling that it isn't exactly stack issues, but that I was using realloc and the movement of memory was invalidating the pointer stored in the hash!

Comment: Daniel, can you clarify the scope of func_entry new_fe;? If this is a local var in a func then it's absolutely a case of your global array pointing to a local, freed stack variable. You would need to allocate the func_entry on the heap using a malloc or new call.

Answer (score 0):

Pointers always are of the same size whether its a pointer to a struct or a generic pointer (char * in olden days, void * in ANSI standard.)

Here's a simple example I whipped out so that you could understand structures, pointers (not in detail though but you get the idea.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct person {
    char *name;
    int age;
};

void print(void *);

int main()
{
    struct person *david;

    if ((david = (struct person *)malloc(sizeof(struct person))) != NULL) {
        david->name = strdup("David");
        david->age = 40;
        printf("sizeof david = %d, sizeof person = %d\n", sizeof david,
               sizeof(struct person));
        print((void *)david);
    }
}

void print(void *p)
{
    struct person *pp = (struct person *)p;
    printf("sizeof p = %d, sizeof pp = %d\n%s %d\n", sizeof p, sizeof pp,
           pp->name, pp->age);
}
```

**Output**

```
sizeof david = 8, sizeof person = 16
sizeof p = 8, sizeof pp = 8
David 40
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Pointers need not all have the same size. They tend to have on modern desktop OSs, but for exotic hardware, there are examples where some pointers have different sizes.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the answer but it doesn't really help that much with my question. I'm fairly familiar with this basic stuff. In fact I think pointers can sometimes be of different sizes. First of all there is 32 vs 64 bit and secondly in some systems function pointers sizes can vary: http://c-faq.com/ptrs/generic.html

Comment: Just to clarify my statement, pointer sizes on the same machine are all same.  Only on older DOS boxes there were near and far pointers they were different, but that's a non-standard.

Comment: Daniel, did you get any warnings when compiling?  Is `PyAutoHashtable_Get` returning a `func_entry *`?  Otherwise you need to cast it to `func_entry *`.  Then you could use fe_entry itself to operate on the structure.

Answer (score 0):

It certainly looks as if something is writing over that data structure. The pointer value `0x6e6f74656c656b73` which you are seeing looks very suspicious indeed - it is ASCII for `"noteleks"`, which is `"skeleton"` backwards. Perhaps this might give you an idea of what is overwriting your data.

Comment: Thanks. Skeleton is certainly a string which appears often in my code base. Sounds like I might have a deeper memory corruption somewhere. Eek.